# Could plastic or metal cans damage my oven?

Tags: baking, oven

Is it possible to put vinyl plastic and metal cans in the oven at 200 degrees F for roughly 5-10 minutes?

More specifically, I was came across DIY Vinyl Bowls where you place the vinyl record over a metal can for 5-10 minutes in the oven, it should become really flimsy and then take it out to form it into a bowl.

I can easily watch over the oven for the time duration but I'm mostly concerned that there would be some sort of plastic explosion or something that might break the oven.

Thank you!

Comment: So... This has nothing to do with food or cooking?

Comment: Benefit of the doubt: It is about equipment (the oven). And no, I have never had any problems with this DIY project. Use a sheet of parchment uderneath just to make sure nothing sticks anywhere.

Comment: Most pertinent aspect for us would be keeping the oven safe for food preparation when used for such craft projects. Some tutorials recommend boiling the record in water instead (http://www.afunandfrugallife.com/one-minute-record-album-bowls/), which would have the added advantage that temperature is self-limiting to 212°F, and that you could use a cheap, damaged or out of use pot, and no longer use that pot for food if any doubt arises. Nutrient loss from boiling might be a concern though.

Comment: Do you really want to do this? Vinyl records have become much more appreciated in recent years. There's something special about analog music contained in a physical object — it's just not the same when you download a digitized song from the Internet. It'd be a shame to destroy an irreplaceable record that someone (perhaps in the future) would enjoy listening to.

Comment: As water boils at 212 degrees F, if you can safely pour boiling water in it without it melting/becoming soft, then you should be fine as long as the oven thermometer is correct. If the container can withstand boiling water, you could put it in the oven at 200 degrees F forever without it melting.

Answer (score 5):

You are taking me *way* back here. Back in my teens I used to do this as a fun project - I used [Plexiglass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poly(methyl_methacrylate)) (acrylic glass) instead of old vinyl records (people still used record players back then!), but the principle stays the same.

No, your oven won't suffer if you are careful.

- The metal can / bowl / heat-proof object underneath must be something that can withstand the heat. Yet 200F isn't *that* hot.
- Always put a sheet of parchment or foil between your tray/rack and the can/vinyl setup.
- Watch carefully. As soon as it shows signs of drooping / bending, take it out. You may always put your future bowl back in the oven to heat it more.
- It might stink, so make sure you have a window open and air out the oven afterwards.
  *Do not try to bake cookies and this at the same time* ;-)

Comment: +1, I was writing the same sort of thing after my comment got too long.

Answer (score 5):

Watch it like a hawk and open the door as soon as it's drooped.  It's not a cake, so you can always shut the door again if it's not quite made it.

As @Stephie says, work on something disposable.

Plastic won't explode unless it's got an air bubble in it.  Even then, any thermoplastic used in this sort of project (i.e. any plastic that melts in your oven) is likely to melt before the air gets too hot, and will pop gently.  I'd be inclined to ventilate the oven well afterwards, and not cook immediately (you could acheive this by doing your craft project just after finishing cooking something, so long as the plastic doesn't smell).